# i can't get multiple rows into array from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, for-loop

i can't get multiple rows into array from mysql database? i have code but it is not working or not showing all rows when i echo into textbox?

```
<?php 
if(is_array($_SESSION['pid']))
{
  $pid = join(',',$_SESSION['pid']); 
  $result=mysql_query("SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid='$pid'") 
            or die("Id    Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
  $results= array();
  $i=0; // add the new line
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $results[$i] = $row['wid'];
    $i++;
  }
  $results;
}
$max=count($results);
for($j=0; $j<$max; $j++)
{
?>
<input type="text" name="wid[]" value="<?php echo $results[$j]; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: nice hole for sql injection good luck

Comment: Why is `$results;` after while lop

Comment: @NullPointer thanks for the support but i have another issue can u solve it please?

Comment: @FarhanDharsi I suspect you mean `pid IN ($pid)`, but yes, injection is a problem here.

Comment: what is for `$results;` ?

Comment: @FarhanDharsi make a good use of both answer i bet you will have it solved...

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson what kind of injection on which code?

Comment: @FarhanDharsi If someone passes in a pid value similar to `';DROP DATABASE mydatabase;SELECT '` you may be in trouble since you'll build the SQL `SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid='';DROP DATABASE mydatabase;SELECT ''`. The mid part being no fun.

Answer (score 2):

The line `join(',',$_SESSION['pid'])` makes me think that you want to select multiple rows by their `pid`. Try to make use of `IN` operator:

```
SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist
WHERE pid IN ($pid)
```

Answer (score 2):

your query is wrong, use this query

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid IN($pid) ")
```

Comment: what is difference between above answer and your ?

Comment: yogesh i used this query but results are still same only fetch one row?

Comment: @FarhanDharsi Run this query in `phpmyadmin` and check how many rows it returns. And also remove this line `$results;` after while loop.

Comment: yes i tried that query and fetching alll rows from this query ... in phpmyadmin

Comment: @FarhanDharsi after while loop use `print_r($results);` and see that what it contains.

Comment: @FarhanDharsi So it means that your while loop runs for 1 time. Check your query again which you used in phpmyadmin and in php code.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar so what should i do now?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$results= array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $results[] = $row['wid'];
}
```

And For Loop as.

```
$max = count($results);
for($j=0; $j<$max; $j++)
{
?>
    <input type="text" name="wid[]" value="<?php echo $results[$j]; ?>" />
<?php
}
?>
```